# custom enumeration, a combination of a letter and roman numbers

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

How can I have enumeration in the following format?

ai) text

aii) text

aiii) text
...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `enumitem` package you can do: `\begin{enumerate}[label={a\roman*)}]`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={a\roman*)}]
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @andy, my pleasure.